# Wrap a variable inside implode function with single quotes

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a query using an array inside the implode function.

```
$dosages = implode(" AND CONCAT(prescription,'-',dosage) =",$doses);
$q=$this->db->query("SELECT account_num 
                     FROM ( 
                     SELECT account_num, CONCAT(prescription,'-',dosage) as script 
                     FROM ci_prescription_history 
                     )a 
                     WHERE script=".implode(' AND script=',$doses));
```

MySQL keeps saying "Unknown column 'Advair' in 'where clause'". I just want to know if it is possible to wrap the variable inside the implode function with single quotes so when it gets parsed it reads out like this

```
SELECT account_num 
FROM ( SELECT account_num, CONCAT(prescription,'-',dosage) as script 
FROM ci_prescription_history 
)a 
WHERE script='Advair-230/21' AND script='Advair-250/50'
```

Comment: 1. Aren't just missing one single quote? 2. This `AND` clause will never return any records.

Comment: Your right I just ran this query in phpmyadmin and it did not return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the quotes to your query and to `implode()`, like this:

```
$q=$this->db->query("SELECT account_num 
                 FROM ( 
                 SELECT account_num, CONCAT(prescription,'-',dosage) as script 
                 FROM ci_prescription_history 
                 )a 
                 WHERE script='" . implode("' AND script ='", $doses)) . "'";
```

Comment: Ok I used your example and it removed the error but I know I should've gotten back two rows but I received an empty result set. Also I think you make have a type after WHERE script='" . implode("' AND script ='", $doses)) . '"'; I think you want WHERE script='" . implode("' AND script ='", $doses)."'"); But I could be wrong

Comment: Probably because you're using `AND` in your query, and you should be using `OR`: `WHERE script='" . implode("' OR script ='", $doses)) . "'";`

Comment: But I want the records that have both of the prescriptions not just one this is the reason I am not using the OR statement. How could I accomplish this if it is possible

Comment: Well you can't put two conditions on a single column. What you're attempting to do is say "Find me all of the records where ID is 5 AND ID is 10". It's contradictory, at most only one of those conditions can ever be satisfied, which makes the AND always find zero rows.

Comment: is there anyway of accomplishing this?

Comment: I think I managed to get it to work by using your method and adding an extra where clause to look up the account number and it seems to be working fine

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Here is what I did to fix it

```
 foreach ($accounts as $account) {
     $q=$this->db->query("SELECT account_num 
     FROM ( 
     SELECT account_num, CONCAT(prescription,'-',dosage) as script 
     FROM ci_prescription_history 
     )a 
     WHERE script='".implode("' OR script ='",$doses)."' AND account_num=$account");
 }
```

Comment: Ok maybe I jump the gun too soon. After testing the query I realized it is still not giving me the correct result set. I used this expression "script IN('".implode("','",$doses)."')")" and it cut down the amount or rows that should not be there, displayed the row I should get but also displaying rows a few rows that should not be there. I am not the best MySQL person around so any help is appreciated.